# How to update reducer store

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

I have store like this

```
export const list = [
    {
        id: 0,
        tableName: 'example',
        tasks: [
            {
                task_id: 0, 
                task_short: 'lorem',
                task_full: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
                time_created: '10:20',
                time_created: null, 
            },
            {
                task_id: 1, 
                task_short: 'andsf',
                task_full: 'lorem ipsum tes tes est',
                time_created: '13:20',
                time_created: null, 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

if I change **tableName** or adding new one using this reducer

```
import { list } from './list'

export default (state = list, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action
    switch(type) {
        case 'ADD_TABLE':
            return [...state, payload]
        case 'DELL_TABLE':
            return  state.filter( ( tabl ) => tabl.id != payload )   
        case 'CHANGE_TITLE':
            let basket = state.map( bas => bas.id == payload.id ? bas.tableName = payload.val : bas )
            return [...state]
        case 'ADD_TASK':
            const newer = state.map( tas =>  tas.id == payload.id ? tas.tasks.push(payload.t) : tas)
            return [...state]

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

all works!!

but if I pushing new task in **tasks** , in console it stored, but not renders.

For making it render, I have to change **tableName** , and after it all is appears

I suppose the problem in here

```
case 'ADD_TASK':
                const newer = state.map( tas =>  tas.id == payload.id ? tas.tasks.push(payload.t) : tas)
                return [...state]
```

here is demo 
http://kanban.antus.pro/

and repo [enter link description here](https://github.com/Antoskin/kanban-board/blob/master/src/reducer/tableReducer.js)

Answer (score 1):

`Array.push()` changes initial array, that's anti-pattern in redux https://redux.js.org/faq/immutabledata

You should change this row

`const newer = state.map( tas =>  tas.id == payload.id ? tas.tasks.push(payload.t) : tas)`

on this one

`const newer = state.map( tas =>  tas.id == payload.id ? [...tas.tasks, payload.t] : tas)`

so you will not mutate initial `tas.tasks` array

try not to use methods from this list in reducer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods

Comment: I changed like you have wrote, but still the same :(

Comment: I understood the issue, you save result of `state.map` in `newer`, but return `[...state]`

so try 

`return state.map( tas =>  tas.id == payload.id ? [...tas.tasks, payload.t] : tas)`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
TaskItem.render
src/components/task/TaskItem.js:11
   8 |  const { parentID, task } = this.props
   9 |  //console.log(task)
  10 | 
> 11 |  const taskItem = task.map( task => 
     | ^  12 |      <p key={task.task_id}> {task.task_short} </p>
  13 |  )

Comment: When I push using sprites, so it return only array **tasks**,

Comment: `return state.map( tas => tas.id == payload.id ? { ...tas, tasks: [...tas.tasks, payload.t] } : tas)`

Comment: Oh pal, thank You so much!!!)))) I love you ))) This stuck was from yesterday mornin, huh.. I'm happy =)